# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'session' not found

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'session' not found in C:\var\www\html\tools\inc\constants.php:122 Stack trace: #0 C:\var\www\html\tools\config.php(92): require_once() #1 C:\var\www\html\tools\header.php(1): require_once('C:\var\www\html...') #2 C:\var\www\html\tools\index.php(1): require_once('C:\var\www\html...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\var\www\html\tools\inc\constants.php on line 122

The code in question: lines 121-138

```
if(php_sapi_name() !== 'cli'){
  $session = new session();

  session_set_save_handler(array($session, 'open'),
                           array($session, 'close'),
                           array($session, 'read'),
                           array($session, 'write'),
                           array($session, 'destroy'),
                           array($session, 'gc'));
  register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
  session_start();
}
if(DEBUG){
  ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth',-1);
  ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data',-1);
  ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children',-1);
  set_time_limit(240);
}
```

I don't know how to fix it and I couldn't find anything online. I'm running php7 and I thought that there would be no issues. Is there anyway to fix this? I've tried calling other sessions and etc.

Another file that's called:

```html
<?php
class session implements \SessionHandlerInterface {

    public function __construct() {
      // session_set_save_handler(
      //       array(&$this, 'open'),
      //       array(&$this, 'close'),
      //       array(&$this, 'read'),
      //       array(&$this, 'write'),
      //       array(&$this, 'destroy'),
      //       array(&$this, 'gc')
      //   );
      // session_start();
      // register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');
    }

    public function open($savePath, $session_name) {
      $db = new database(TRUE);
      $db->query("INSERT INTO session
                  SET session_id = :sessionName,
                  session_data = ''
                  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                  UPDATE session_lastaccesstime = NOW()");
      $db->bind(':sessionName',$session_name);
      $db->execute();
      return true;
    }

    public function close() {
        return true;
    }

    public function read($id) {
      $db = new database(TRUE);
      $db->query("SELECT * FROM session WHERE session_id = :id");
      $db->bind(':id',$id);
      if ($db->execute()) {
        $result = $db->single(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result["session_data"].'';
      }
      return '';
    }

    public function write($id, $data) {
      if ($data == null) {
        return true;
      }
      $db = new database(TRUE);
      $db->query("INSERT INTO session 
        SET session_id = ?, 
        session_data = ?
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE session_data = ?");
      $db->bind(1,$id);
      $db->bind(2,$data);
      $db->bind(3,$data);
      $db->execute();
      return true;
      //session_write_close();
    }

    public function destroy($id) {
      $db = new database(TRUE);
      $db->query("DELETE FROM session WHERE session_id = :id");
      $db->bind(':id',$id);
      $db->execute();
      return true;
    }

    public function gc($maxlifetime) {
      $db = new database(TRUE);
      $db->query("DELETE FROM session 
        WHERE session_lastaccesstime < DATE_SUB(NOW(),
        INTERVAL " . $lifetime . " SECOND)");
      $db->execute();
      return true;
    }
}
```

I tried loading in the class via placing

> require_once("inc/classes/session.php")

right after the if statement, but that just opened up more issues and more classes not being called. I'll link to the GitHub so you can see what really is going on.

https://github.com/nfreader/newSS13tools

Comment: Do you have `session` class somewhere? Do you load it?

Comment: There is no basic object oriented session implementation in PHP. Either use the [PHP session functions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php), or tell us about the session class you are using :-)

Comment: Do you even _have_ a class called `session`?

Comment: I don't believe the code that I'm trying to fix has a class called session, however, I've been trying to add that class, but so far I've been unsuccessful.

Comment: Did you load/include that class? Are you in the same namespace? (seems like the session-class is in the root namespace).

Comment: Loading that class leads to a ton more issues in the site. I'll link to the GitHub

Comment: No need. Conclusion: not loading the class = you can't use it. Loading the class leads to ton more issues = concentrate of sorting those out. You don't really have any other option. Unless you decide not to use that class at all.

Comment: It seems that when I link the session class, it says that the session class can't find a database class. there's a class folder so I assume that the hierarchy, or the way it's run isn't in a traditional way.

Comment: The repository you've linked uses composer to load classes. Maybe you should do that too, that way you don't have to use `include` calls over and over

Comment: I've done a composer install, however. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Okay so I ran a complete composer install, but it STILL does not want to work. This seems to be an issue with composer.

Comment: For some reason I can't use the autoloader, even after I set it up and installed everything. The index file calls on the config, which calls on the autoloader, however, it still does not load every class.

Answer (score 0):

I see no answer on here, but I learned today how to do this.

Folder structure:

```
WebRoot
  |
  - class
  |  |
  |  - TestName
  |    |
  |    - testInterface.php
  |    - testClass.php
  - start.php
```

start.php

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $class = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);
    include '/class/' . $class . '.php';
});
```

testInterface.php

```
namespace TestName;

interface testInterface {

}
```

testClass.php

```
namespace TestName;

class testClass implements testInterface {

}
```

The important line I found was the first line in the spl_autoload. I was getting back slash errors. (windows separator on a linux system). Simply replacing that double back slash fixed my error.

Source of my fix: [The first result using some carefully crafted foogling](https://supunkavinda.blog/php/autoload-classes-namespaces)

The question I asked: load namespaces class with spl_autoload